# Possible to complete recaptcha that I have no direct access to?

Tags: php, curl, captcha, recaptcha

I automated a task of login in and updating a status on a website using PHP with CURL but the site now requires the account that is being used to complete a one time recaptcha for the web servers IP (can login from my own just fine), probably because it changed. Is there any way to complete said captcha from the webserver or am I doomed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one time captcha per IP? set up a proxy from your server, log in via the proxy on your browser, solve the captcha from your web browser, after you have solved it, make curl on the server log in from the same ip, with the same cookie session as your browser used. use CURLOPT_COOKIE to steal the cookie session from the browser with curl. use the javascript `document.cookie`  to get the cookie content from your browser. and make sure not to "logout" on your browser! as that would probably destroy the cookie session curl is now using, and would require re-solving the captcha.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great solution!